# Center a text between to floating elements

Tags: html, css, center, element

I am working on a navigation bar for my website. The navigation bar contains a menu icon, a header 'Reviews' and a search icon. The icons need to have a distance of 3% from the border. The problem is that I can't figure it out how I center the text. I think the problem is with the floating elements and I don't know how I center a floating element between to other elements(in this case two icons). I hope someone could provide me with an answer :)

This is the result:

[the navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuZ3T.png)

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#nav {
  width: 94%;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 3%;
}

.menuButton {
  float: left;
}

#nav h1 {
  float: left;
}

.searchButton {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> Reviews </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<div id="dropMenu"></div>

<body>
  <div id="nav">
    <img src="menu.jpg" class="menuButton">
    <h1> REVIEWS. </h1>
    <img src="search.jpg" class="searchButton">

  </div>

  <div id="content"></div>

  <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this output are you expecting

[Check output in codepen.io](http://codepen.io/mandar262/pen/xgowab?editors=1100)

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 3%;
}

.menuButton {
  float: left;
}



.searchButton {
  float: right;
}

.a {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title> Reviews </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>


<div id="dropMenu">



</div>

<body>

  <div id="nav">
    <img src="menu.jpg" class="menuButton">
    <h1 class="a"> REVIEWS. </h1>
    <img src="search.jpg" class="searchButton">


  </div>

  <div id="content">



  </div>

  <div id="footer">



  </div>


</body>
```

Comment: Not exactly, the search-button is now under the the 'Reviews'-text and the Menu-icon. I want the three elements inline with the 'Reviews'-text centered between the two icons .

Comment: can u share your full code so that i can know what is the problem

Comment: on which screen are u viewing the site

Comment: I sent the full code in my question. I am viewing the website on my iMac.

Comment: do u have any padding or margin for search buttom?

Comment: remove float for search button and adjust by using `margin` or `position`

Comment: I used padding in my navigation-div

Comment: reducing the width of the navigation div can also work

Comment: i changed the width of the navigation div to 94%. But it can't figure it out how i center the 'Reviews'-text and have the search button inline

Comment: reduce more width

Answer (score 2):

You may use the flex boxmodel and margins :

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#nav {
  width: 94%;
  background-color: blue;
  /* see center */
  background-image:linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 50%);
  margin: 3%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menuButton {
  float: left;
  margin: auto auto auto 0;
}

#nav h1 {
  float: left;
}

.searchButton {
  margin: auto 0 auto auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Reviews </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<div id="dropMenu"></div>
<body>
  <div id="nav">
    <img src="menu.jpg" class="menuButton">
    <h1> REVIEWS. </h1>
    <img src="search.jpg" class="searchButton">
  </div>
  <div id="content"></div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**edit**.

**Considering only float**, then float elements should be ahead in the flux to let other **non-floatting**  elements comes in between, so `h1` can be standing in between and get `text-align` or be centered via `display` and `margin`.

float won't allow vertical centering of elements where  flex does .

- text-align and no float for h1

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#nav {
  width: 94%;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 3%;
}

.menuButton {
  float: left;
}

#nav h1 {
 display:table;/* shrinks on itself */
 margin:auto;
}

.searchButton {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropMenu"></div>


<div id="nav">
  <img src="menu.jpg" class="menuButton">
  <img src="search.jpg" class="searchButton">
  <h1> REVIEWS. </h1>

</div>

<div id="content"></div>

<div id="footer"></div>
```

- or display and margin without float for h1

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#nav {
  width: 94%;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 3%;
}

.menuButton {
  float: left;
}

#nav h1 {
 text-align:center
}

.searchButton {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropMenu"></div>


<div id="nav">
  <img src="menu.jpg" class="menuButton">
  <img src="search.jpg" class="searchButton">
  <h1> REVIEWS. </h1>

</div>

<div id="content"></div>

<div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: explain downvote and where it doesn't work, **to make your downvote usefull**. I might have misunderstood the question, but as is, i'll keep the answer online. thanks

Comment: @Soccerlife, no probleme, i knew it worked . Can you accept one of the answers (both works as you said) or at least upvote people who helped you efficiently ?

Comment: Im new to StackOverflow, i dont know to  do that,

Comment: @Soccerlife you have a number with up & down arrows to let you, upvote or downvote an answer or a question. If you asked a question you should also have something aside the answer to accept it or select the one that you choose as answering to your question . you can accep/selectt only one. You can vote once on each answers. you also can reverse/delete your vote clicking again on it. :) Welcome

Comment: Thank you, i dont see that option yet because i only have six of something haha